# How to configure sendmailR to issue STARTTLS

Tags: r, smtp, sendmailr

I'm trying to send emails from R using `sendmailR` package using the following code, which unfortunately fails :

```
## Set mail contents
from <- sprintf('<sendmailR@%s>', Sys.info()[4])
to <- '<slackline@gmail.com>'
subject <- 'Feeding Plots'
body <- list('Latest feeding graph', mime_part(feeding.plot,
                                               name = "feeding"))
## Set control parameters
control <- sendmail_options(verboseShow = TRUE, 
                            smtpServer ="smtp.gmail.com", 
                            smtpPort = 587, 
                            smtpSTARTTLS = '',
                            blocking = FALSE)
sendmail(from,
         to,
         subject,
         msg = body,
         control = control,
         headers)
<< 220 mx.google.com ESMTP xt1sm884721wjb.17 - gsmtp
>> HELO  kimura
<< 250 mx.google.com at your service
>> MAIL FROM:  <sendmailR@kimura>
<< 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. xt1sm884721wjb.17 - gsmtp
Error in wait_for(code) : 
  SMTP Error: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. xt1sm884721wjb.17 - gsmtp
```

The [sendmailR manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sendmailR/sendmailR.pdf%E2%80%8E) doesn't mention how to configures `STARTTLS` although it does indicate that additional arguments can be passed, which is why I have included the option `smtpSTARTLS = ''` based on whats mentioned in some other threads ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802360/email-an-attachment-in-r-with-gmail/7802766) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509699/must-issue-a-starttls-command-first)).  I've tried playing with the argument for `smtpSTARTTLS` and setting it to `TRUE` but no joy.

Any pointers to documentation or solutions would be most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand it, `sendmailR` doesn't support any type of login to the SMTP server, hence, gmail is basically unusable. You can only use the package if you are within the right network and set up a server that is only reachable within the network I guess (i.e., one NOT using authentication).

The alternative is the [`mail`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mail/index.html) package (in which you cannot use your own address).

The reference from the [sendmailR documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sendmailR/sendmailR.pdf) is:

> SMTP AUTH is currently unsupported.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that I hadn't realised TLS was related to authentication.  I'd seen the `mail` package mentioned whilst reading up on `sendmailR`, will consider that but have [sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org/) installed on my system so may see if I can get them to work together.

Answer (score 2):

You could give the new mailR package a shot that allows SMTP authorization: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mailR/index.html

The following call should then work:

```
send.mail(from = "slackline@gmail.com",
          to = "slackline@gmail.com",
          subject = "Subject of the email",
          body = "Body of the email",
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "slackline", passwd = "PASSWORD", ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this clear example. We need to pay close attention to the smtp arguments' names which are not consistent across packages; user.name (not username) and passwd (not pw nor password).

Comment: `mailR` does allow SMTP authentication, but unfortunately not STARTTLS (as described [here](https://r-bar.net/mailr-smtp-webmail-starttls-tls-ssl/)).