# Attaching pdf file from website sending email

Tags: python, email, pdf, smtp, message

Hi was able to send an email using this code below, I am using SMTP:

```
message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
message['From'] = 'test@gmail.com'
message['To'] = 'test@gmail.com'
email_body = '<html><body>Hello!</body></html>'
message.attach(MIMEText(email_body, 'html'))
text = message.as_string()
```

Then send as:

```
smtpserver.sendmail(from_address, to_address, message_body)
```

when I add attachment from web like this url: http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf

I added this code:

```
    from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
    from email import encoders

    pdf = 'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf'
    filename = 'test_pdf'
    import requests
    webf = requests.get(pdf)
    attachment = webf.content
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload(attachment)
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                    "attachment", filename=filename)
```

It send but doesnt attach the pdf.

I tried searching online cant seem to find a solution for this.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @cardamom its 2.7

Comment: Try changing 'octet-stream' to 'pdf' as per [here](https://www.sitekickr.com/snippets/python/send-html-email-attachments) if that doesn't work try this solution with MIMEText [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921188/how-to-send-email-with-pdf-attachment-in-python)