# Sending custom Mime Types Google App Engine Email

Tags: python, google-app-engine, smtp, mime-types, smtplib

Hi I've just found out that I can't use smtplib to send emails from GAE, but I need to specify custom mime-types as in:

```
part = MIMEBase('application', "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
part.set_payload( doc )
Encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % "ackReceived.docx")
msg.attach(part)
```

If I try to use the api in the documented way it sends the attachment with 'application/msword' which is causing my docx to corrupt.

Can I specify the mime-type manually using google's mail api?

**Edit:** A little more about the problem I face when my docx is sent by mail api:

smtplib sends the attachment like this:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ackReceived.docx"

UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCCVgdJnwEAAMgIAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbMWWS0/DMBCE
70j8h8hXlLhwQAg17YHHEZAo4mzsTWMRP2Qvj/571k1bIaiaiDbiEilZz3wzsSJnPP00TfYOIWpn
S3ZajFgGVjql7bxkT7Pb/IJlEYVVonEWSraAyKaT46PxbOEhZqS2sWQ1or/kPMoajIiF82BpUrlg...
```

Google mail api sends the same file like this:

```
Content-Type: application/msword
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ackReceived.docx"

PK�����!�‚VIŸ��È�����[Content_Types].xmlÅ–KOÃ0„ïHü‡ÈW”¸p@5íÇ(âlìMc?d/þ{ÖM[!¨šˆ6â)YÏ|3±"g<ý4Mö!jgKvZŒXV:¥í¼dO³Ûü‚e…U¢qJ¶€È¦“ã£ñlá!f¤¶±d5¢¿ä<ÊŒˆ…ó`iR¹`Òm˜s/ä«˜?Î¹tÁbŽÉƒMÆ×P‰·³›OzÜ&!9Ë®Úu    U2á}£¥@ó4å[uÞÎè´IÜô|»"@w Þ­úÑ'_u)H¹\kíãÉ*Ó=½Ì d"à0dÇ?\P\9ùfQì®¶…çªJKØè“›NBŒ´K¦)6#´íÌqÑ@<|ŠÖ·'þYc}SU ±Oó¤-~i»i€Hñ†¨»rîŒð/ƒ¥øfÞ¤r­Ã!ö~cÝ¬(ÃÚ¹3B
BA8=|‚Ö¸'ÿìßøi³éß÷äÐ¿7Ÿxâ¥!¬¬;C ”Ð^÷ß‰¥Í.$­|ÎG:yÃj¯¼¤Î©°‡€z÷—¶!’õÞý Ö...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't specify custom mime types using Google AppEngine e-mail.

In order to send e-mail via Google AppEngine through Google you need to use the Mail API provided. You can see why .docx is using the content type `application/msword` here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/mail-with-headers-attachments. You might want to submit an issue to the issue tracker in order to resolve this.

It may be worth looking at 3rd party e-mail providers such as [Amazon's SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/). I've personally been using Amazon's SES to get around a lot of the lack of features and restrictions in GAE's Mail API (though Google is constantly improving this API).

You can use the [boto library](https://github.com/boto/boto) to communicate with AWS SES and send [RAW e-mail messages](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/ses.html#boto.ses.connection.SESConnection.send_raw_email). (Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python) for an example on how to create the e-mail, small modifications may be needed for your purposes)

Comment: I'm slightly disappointed that I have to include an extra library/service in my project but I must say it works rather well, and exactly as you've described. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Happy to help, what service did you end up using?

Comment: I went with boto to send raw email's by SES

Comment: Is this link relevant anymore? Where is the application/msword on the page?