# How to send an email with an attachment in python

Tags: python, email, attachment

I have a script that creates a csv file that I need to also send in an email as an attachment.  I haven't been able to find a working example of how to do this so far.  Is there "standard" code to do this?  Can someone provide a good example of how to do this?  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: search before you create a new question! Your exact issue is described and solved in this SO-question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python

Comment: I'v actually already tried that example, but it didn't work for me.  It's also 3 years old and was wondering if there was an updated answer or newer code.

Comment: what environment are you using? I have previously used the mail-command in Linux and simply called it from python.

Comment: Linux 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.  Are you talking about the mailx command?  I see -a gives you the ability to attach a file.

Comment: yes, I run the command from python and it has worked fine to send attachment.