# Error while sending Mail with attachement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import smtplib, os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import encoders

os.chdir(path)


def send_mail(send_from,send_to,subject,text,files,server,port,username='',password='',isTls=True):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = send_to
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime = True)
    msg['Subject'] = 'Test'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open("Olaf.xlsx", "rb").read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; 
    filename="Olaf.xlsx"')
    msg.attach(part)

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.web.de', 587)
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login('test@test.de', 'pw')
```

At this part the error occurs: NameError: name 'msg' is not defined. But whats wrong?
Here is where I got the code from: [add excel file attachment when sending python email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346001/add-excel-file-attachment-when-sending-python-email)

```
    smtp.sendmail('xy','xyz', msg.as_string())

    smtp.quit()
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of the code in your question. It looks like you are trying to access the variable `msg` defined _in_ the function, outside of it

Comment: Thank you really much, i fixed it

Comment: I wonder how doesn't it raise a `NameError` on `os.chdir(path)` as you haven't defined `path` anywhere. Then it should raise a `SyntaxError` on the `part.add_header...` line. Strangely enough, the only error your code shouldn't be rising is the one you're saying it does.

Comment: In my code the path is wirtten in G:\ etc. just for the example i renamed it. So it works now, Thanks for the fast answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
import smtplib, os
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

emaillist=['to@gmail.com'] # Receipient email address
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['Subject'] = 'Arrest Warrent' # mail subject line
msg['From'] = 'xyz@gmail.com' # From email address
msg['To'] = ', '.join(emaillist)

part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")

# Provide the path of the file to be attached in the mail
part.set_payload(open('C:'+os.sep+'Users'+os.sep+'abhijit'+os.sep+'Desktop'+os.sep+'WarrentDetails.txt', "rb").read())
Encoders.encode_base64(part)

part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="WarrentDetails.txt"')

msg.attach(part)
msg.add_header('To', msg['From'])
text = "Dear Sir, \n\n An arrest warrent has been generated due to XYZ reason by ZZZ complain.\n YOU MUST APPEAR IN PERSON TO RESOLVE THIS MATTER. \n\n Regards,\n FBI :)"
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
msg.attach(part1)

# provide SMTP details of the host and its port number
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com",465)
# If the host supports TLS then enable the below 2 lines of code
# server.ehlo()
# server.starttls()

server.login("xyz@gmail.com", "password")

server.sendmail(msg['From'], emaillist , msg.as_string())
```

More details on this can be found at [this blog](http://abhijitbangera.com/python-mailer-sending-email-with-attachment-using-python-script/).