# send excel attachment through outlook using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code i'm using to send excel as a attachment to outlook email using python 2.7 version. If i command the attachment lines in the code, i could send the text email but not the attached email.Also i'm not receiving any error. Can somebody please help me identify the issue in the code.

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import date
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import smtplib
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

server = smtplib.SMTP(host='xxxxx.net', port=25)
fromaddr = "aaaaaaaaabb@outlook.com"
RECIPIENTS = "aaaaaaaaabb@outlook.com"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
body = """
   Hi Team, <br>
   <br>
   Please find the attached data sync validation betweeen Reltio and BDS .<br>
   <br>
   Please reach out to Team for any questions.<br>
   <br>
   Regards,<br>
   xxxx <br>
   Support Team<br>"""

subject = 'Reltio and BDS Data Sync for EU Org'
msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative", None, [MIMEText(body, 'html','utf-8')])
msg['To'] = RECIPIENTS
msg['From'] = "axxxxxyyy@.net"
msg['Subject'] = subject
stg = MIMEBase('application', 'vnd.ms-excel')
stg.set_payload(open("EU_Consent.xlsx", "rb").read())
encoders.encode_base64(stg)
stg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename="EU_Consent.xlsx")
msg.attach(stg)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, RECIPIENTS, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Could you please try these solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346001/add-excel-file-attachment-when-sending-python-email

Comment: Hi Alex but that link is not working for me. the above code works fine in my local system but not working in Linux server.

Answer (score 1):

```
path='/xxx/yyyy/zzz/file.xlsx'
fp=open(path, 'rb')
stg = MIMEBase('application','vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
stg.set_payload(fp.read())
fp.close()
```