# trying to send email with xlsx attachment with python

Tags: python, excel, email, xlsx, smtplib

I'm trying to sending email with attachment with below python code, but the xlsx attachment always broken in the email, I guess there's something wrong with the encoding, Content-Type and Content-Transfer-Encoding in part3 but I changed many Content-Type but still failed to open the xlsx attachment. Can anyone give some suggestion? thank you very much in advance!

I've seen the answer in [add excel file attachment when sending python email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346001/add-excel-file-attachment-when-sending-python-email)

and I just want to know what's wrong with my code, and how to correct it to make the xlsx attachment openable.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib
import base64

filename = "xxxx.xlsx"

# Read a file and encode it into base64 format
fo = open(filename, 'rb')
filecontent = fo.read()
encodedcontent = base64.b64encode(filecontent)  # base64

sender = 'donotreply@xxxx.com'
reciever = 'xxxx@xxxx.com'

marker = "MARKER"

body ="""
This is a test email to send an attachement.
"""
# Define the main headers.
part1 = """From: xxxx <donotreply@xxxx.com>
To: <xxxx@xxxx.com>
Subject: Sending Attachement
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s
--%s
""" % (marker, marker)

# Define the message action
part2 = """Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

%s
--%s
""" % (body,marker)

# Define the attachment section
part3 = """Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; name=\"%s\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s

%s
--%s--
""" %(filename, filename, encodedcontent, marker)
message = part1 + part2 + part3

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP(host='xxxx.com',port=25)
   smtpObj.sendmail(from_addr=sender,to_addrs=reciever,msg=message)
   print ("Successfully sent email")
except Exception as e:
   print (e)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add excel file attachment when sending python email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346001/add-excel-file-attachment-when-sending-python-email)

Comment: @Aditya Thanks Aditya, I've seen this post and it works, I just want to know what's wrong in my code, any comment is appreciated.