# Python Email table from MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, email

I am trying to get the results of a MYSQL query into the body of an email and also as a csv or xls attachment.

My code below works and sends the email only problem is if the results from the MYSQL query are more than a row only the first row shows up in the email.

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
import os
import MySQLdb
import string
import datetime
import time

today = (time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))

#print today

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="-----.com", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="----", # your username
                      passwd="-------", # your password
                      db="dailies") # name of the data base


cursor49=db.cursor()

cursor49.execute("SELECT PLACEMENT_NAME FROM dailies.pub_cpm join placement ON placement.PLACEMENT_id = pub_cpm.PLACEMENT_ID where date(pub_cpm.created) = date(now())")

results49 = cursor49.fetchone()

# Commit your changes in the database
db.commit()

# disconnect from server
db.close()

results50 = "Latest Pub CPM Name(s): %s" % (results49)

gmail_user = "------@gmail.com"
gmail_pwd = "g---a"

mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)



to = ['-----@g-----']

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = ", ".join(to)
msg['Subject'] = "Database Alerts: %s" % (today)

body =  results50

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))


mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()

text = msg.as_string()

mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, text)

# Should be mailServer.quit(), but that crashes...
mailServer.close()
```

Comment: Of course only one shows up. That's all you are asking for: `.fetchone()`

Comment: should it be changed to `.fetchall()`?

Comment: How would I be able to attach it as file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple changes you need to make. First, you need to change your `fetchone()` call to a `fetchall()` call. This will return all results from your `SELECT` query.

Next, you want to write these to a CSV file. Let's do that using the results from our query above:

```
results49 = cursor.fetchall()
fp = open('/tmp/file_name.csv', 'w')    # You pick a name, it's temporary
attach_file = csv.writer(fp)
attach_file.writerows(results49)
fp.close()
```

At this point, you have a file in `/tmp/file_name.csv` (or what ever path and name you picked) that contains your CSV results. The final step is to attach this to an email.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = ", ".join(to)
msg['Subject'] = "Database Alerts: %s" % (today)

body =  results50

part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open("/tmp/file_name.csv", "rb").read())    # This is the same file name from above
Encoders.encode_base64(part)

part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="/tmp/file_name.csv"')

msg.attach(part)
```

I changed your `msg.attach()` function and utilized [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python) from another question.

Once this is done, you still have a file in `/tmp/file_name.csv`. You can delete this safely at this point.

Comment: Only change I hade to made was to `attach_file.writerows(rows)` which should be `attach_file.writerows(results49)` Other than that it worked like a charm.