# Send Mail in Python Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, flask

I have a server that has Anaconda installed which comes with Flask. I am setting up a webapp where users in our company can upload a file for analysis and have the results e-mailed to them. This is all done through our internal network. However, I am not allowed to install Flask extensions (i.e., flask-mail, flask-wtf, etc) and all Google searches for "send mail flask" results in using "flask-mail".

How can I send emails (with a file attachment of the analysis results) using a flask server but without requiring additional extensions?

Comment: This will work fine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python

Comment: If I'm running flask on 127.0.0.1:5000, can I also send mail via the same address and port while flask is running?

Comment: Looks like I'll need to run an smtpd server first too

Comment: You probably have an smtp server in your company (as you said you're setting up a webapp for you company).

Comment: Is it possible to send mail without hooking into the company's SMTP server? I've sent mail previously using Unix sendmail but I wanted to accomplish this exclusively with Python.