# What is the best way to send python console output as email from within the script?

Tags: python, smtplib

I have a python script that does multiple things and prints logs on the console. For now, I have not used any logging mechanism(I am just printing the required messages using `print`) How do I take all the prints and send it out as an email? Do I have to save it all in a variable and pass it to smtplib? or is there a better way?

Sample code

```
for job in fetch.getJobStats():
        if job['userName']+"_"+job['tenantId'] in summaryTotal:
            summary = summaryTotal[job['userName']+"_"+job['tenantId']]
        else:
            summary = Summary(job['userName'], job['tenantId'])
            summaryTotal[summary.user+"_"+summary.tenant] = summary

        summary.jobs.append(Job(job['jobId'], job['jobStatus'], int(job['fileSize'])))
        totalBw += int(job['fileSize'])

    print("Cumulative Size: " + str(totalBw))
    for summaryKey in summaryTotal.keys():
        summary = summaryTotal[summaryKey]

        inprogress = []
        failed = []
        completed = []
        cancelled = []
        totalBwTenantUser = 0

        for job in summary.jobs:
            totalBwTenantUser += job.filesize
            if job.status == "JOBCANCELLED":
                cancelled.append(job.id)
            elif job.status == "JOBCOMPLETED":
                completed.append(job.id)
            elif job.status == "INPROGRESS":
                completed.append(job.id)
            elif job.status == "JOBFAILED":
                completed.append(job.id)

        print("-" * 50)
        print("Tenant: " + summary.tenant)
        print("User  : " + summary.user)
        print("Size    : " + str(totalBwTenantUser))
        print("\n")
        print("INPROGRESS: " + str(inprogress))
        print("COMPLETED : " + str(completed))
        print("CANCELLED : " + str(cancelled))
        print("FAILED    : " + str(failed))
        print("-" * 50)
```

All the prints should be shot off an email.

Comment: Please post your code and way you are saving them, and someone can help you with sending email

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should use the excellent [logging system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) that comes with Python.

Combine it with the [`mailinglogger`](http://pythonhosted.org/mailinglogger/) handler and you have everything you need:

```
import logging

from mailinglogger.SummarisingLogger import SummarisingLogger

handler = SummarisingLogger('from@example.com',
                            ('to@example.com',),
                            subject='[LOGS] %s (hostname)s',
                            mailhost='smtp.example.com')

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                    level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(handler)

logging.info('Sent by email.')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Will try this out

Comment: ERROR: No matching distribution found for SummarisingLogger, how to install?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) library, configure the logging to a file then just read the contents of that file and send it or attach the log file directly to the email you're sending (see [How to send email attachments with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python)).

Comment: python looging library also provides an [SMTPHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler). You can use this to send mail instead of attaching your log file directly.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that!