# MIME Attachments won't send with Subject Line

Tags: python, email, attachment, mime

I'm having trouble with a bit of code sending an email with attachments AND a Subject line.

```
# Code exerpt from Oli:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python
# Emails aren't sending with a subject--need to fix this.
def send_mail(self, send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=None, server="localhost"):
    assert isinstance(send_to, list)

    msg = MIMEMultipart(
        Subject=subject,
        From=send_from,
        To=COMMASPACE.join(send_to),
        Date=formatdate(localtime=True)
    )

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    for f in files or []:
        with open(f, "rb") as fil:
            msg.attach(MIMEApplication(
            fil.read(),
               Content_Disposition='attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f),
               Name=basename(f)
            ))

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()
```

This code sends an email fine, but it is not deliminating the 'Subject' line and the emails it sends have a subject line of "NO SUBJECT.'  Here's what it shows when I print the first part of the MIME msg:

```
From nobody Thu Oct 29 16:17:38 2015
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; date="Thu, 29 Oct 2015 16:17:38 +0000";
to="me@email.com";
from="someserver@somewhere.com"; subject="TESTING";
boundary="===============0622475305469306134=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============0622475305469306134==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Here we go, oh! ho! ho!
--===============0622475305469306134==
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; Content-  Disposition="attachment;
filename=\"Log_Mill.py\""; Name="Log_Mill.py"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

I might be able to figure it out if I plug away for hours and hours, but I'm hoping to avoid the extra work for such a trivial fix.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the Subject etc. as attributes of the multipart container, but that's incorrect.  The headers you want to specify should be passed to the `msg` itself as headers instead, like this:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = send_from
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
```

The output should look more like

```
From nobody Thu Oct 29 16:17:38 2015
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2015 16:17:38 +0000
To: <me@email.com>
From: <someserver@somewhere.com>
Subject: TESTING
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
   boundary="===============0622475305469306134=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============0622475305469306134==
Content-Type: text/plain; .......
```

Comment: So...I had tried that before and it didn't work. Oh well--seems to work now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a package specialised for writing HTML emails, showing pictures inline and easily attach files!

The package I'm referring to is [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) and I'm the developer/maintainer.

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('email@email.com', 'email_pwd')
file_names = ['/local/path/f.mp3', '/local/path/f.txt', '/local/path/f.avi']
yag.send('to@email.com', 'Sample subject', contents = ['This is text'] + filenames)
```

That's all there is to it.

Use `pip install yagmail` to obtain your copy.

Contents can be a list where you also add text, you can just only have the `file_names` as contents, awesome no?

It reads the file, magically determines the encoding, and attached it :)

Read the github for other tricks like passwordless scripts, aliasing and what not.