# Python Reference a folder or files in a folder

Tags: python

Good Afternoon.

I would like to know how to reference files or a folder to a variable in Python.

Lets say i have some files with the following names:

```
161225_file1.txt
161225_file2.txt
161225_file3.txt
161226_file1.txt
161226_file2.txt
161226_file3.txt
161227_file1.txt
161227_file2.txt
161227_file3.txt
```

i want to assign those files to a variable so i can use it in a email script i have, i also only need the files with a certain date.

Right now i only have the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
###############################
#Imports (some library imports)
###############################
import sys
import time
import os
import re
from datetime import date,timedelta
from lib.osp import Connection
from lib.sendmail import *


###############################
#Parameters (some parameters i`ll use to send the email, like the email body message with yesterdays date)
###############################

ndays = 1
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=ndays)
address = 'some.email@gmail.com'
title = '"Email Test %s"' % yesterday
attachments = ''

mail_body = "This is a random message with yesterday`s date %s" % yesterday


###############################
#Paths (Path that contain the home directory and the directory of the files i want to attach)
###############################


homedir = '/FILES/user/emails/'
filesdir = '/FILES/user/emails/TestFolder/'


###############################
#Script
###############################

#starts the mail function  

start_mail()


#whatever message enters here will be in the email`s body.
write_mail(mail_body)



#gets everything you did before this step and sends it vial email.
send_mail(address,title,attachments)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send email attachments with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python)

Comment: What is the issue/question?

Comment: Are you trying to load the filenames into a list? Are you trying to read the contents of the files? Please be more specific.

Comment: If someone nefarious were to see this, they might use something like this to create spam.  Spam is not a good thing.  It uses more energy globally than cryptocurrency.   Its carbon footprint is something like 1/3 of all internet traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) will get  files and subdirectories in a directory.

If you want just files,use os.path:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
    files = [f for f in listdir(homedir) if isfile(join(homedir, f))]
```

And you can find detailed explantion on how to attach file to an email [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python) 
Thanks to [Oli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12870/oli)

```
import smtplib
from os.path import basename
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate


def send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=None,
              server="127.0.0.1"):
    assert isinstance(send_to, list)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    for f in files or []:
        with open(f, "rb") as fil:
            part = MIMEApplication(
                fil.read(),
                Name=basename(f)
            )
            part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
            msg.attach(part)


    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()
```