# Attaching pdf file to an EmailMessage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, pdf, python-3.6

I am trying to set up an automated email sending script. I am using the email module and the `EmailMessage` object from the `email.message` module and am sending the email using the `smtplib` module. I would like to be able to attach a .pdf file to an email but the documentation for the `add_attachment()` method for `EmailMessage()` is not very helpful and I'm not even sure I should be using it.

Here is what I have so far with irrelevant information removed:

```
import time
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

FROM = 'my email'

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.login('my email', 'password')

for line in open('to.csv'):
    line = line.strip()
    fields = line.split(',')

    subject = 'subject'

    email = EmailMessage()

    email['Subject'] = 'subject'
    email['From'] = FROM
    email['To'] = 'to email'


    s.send_message(email)

    print('Sent to {0}'.format(fields[TO]))

    time.sleep(5)

s.quit()
```

How do I go about attaching the pdf file? I searched and saw one answer was using the MIMEText object to add attachments but it did not appear to work pdf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send email attachments with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python)

Answer (score 29):

Late for the answer... but this is what I do:

```
email = EmailMessage()

email['Subject'] = 'subject'
email['From'] = FROM
email['To'] = 'to email'

with open('example.pdf', 'rb') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
    email.add_attachment(content, maintype='application', subtype='pdf', filename='example.pdf')

s.send_message(email)
```

Comment: Short, succinct, and highly useable.  This should be one of the examples included within the [standard python examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html).

Comment: Surely `maintype` here should be `application`?

Comment: @SColvin yes. I can confirm that `maintype='application/pdf'`  results in `Content-Type: application/pdf/pdf`, although most clients won't care and do their own MIME sniffing by looking at `.pdf` in the filename of the attachment. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks man, any idea how to added test body as well?