# How to add pdf attachment in an existing eml file using Python?

Tags: python, email, eml

Currently I am working on eml files and I am newly working on those kind of files:

I had to do change the sender name and send the same eml file to those sender but I want to add .eml file to my existing

I have got successfully changed the changed the sender by using email.parser library using replace header command.

For example:

```
from email.parser import Parser
f = open('C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Message.eml', 'r+')
header = Parser().parse(f)

headers.replace_header(headername, headervalue)
headers.replace_header('to', 'name@gmail.com')
```

But now I am stuck how to add pdf attachment in email body of that same .eml file. Below is an example of an .eml file. In this I want to add an attachment.

Can you guys please help?

.eml file template:

```
Delivered-To: ***@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:ac9:1e03:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id r3csp1380999oci;
        Thu, 6 May 2021 03:24:14 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJxznI2eQK4UcAUk1vJbeKdYMovRwYMwxz4trgXWy7O+V1jklccpi92jvFWplswmqnBJfdpV
X-Received: by 2002:a17:2:94:b9:ec:7fd5:193e with SMTP id w4-20020a1709029a84b02900ec7fd5193emr3638953plp.62.1620296654743;
        Thu, 06 May 2021 03:24:14 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1620296654; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=EH7EGZH8A3o9/LvvqIgO3KaZPU82Jn0iX0/kGV5W/tawujBF7y3qV3Er4lpFtX
         rm1jiy+cH3CPEHEiAyyd3XSuBZFA+AoE8xpoZxXaTxmqB6vBQXVWigVUUTKcsl71CSVs
         xLG7NHWsFABWEdemJY/cnibY85tpk1NpVISzDihAd4IShMKOGlYqoOlyWf06pdyIc2y6
         DZVYrlo/oWsnD2VT5nYiVqMeOwjUKIVg9ACyZIIRpmMQT/2/lutcsrLPMBBJbLK1vpgU
         jpZHu3s++EFPjmuTijNbyvv/5d5RrcsOwvLpWqk
         8U1A==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=from:subject:sender:message-id:to:mime-version:date:dkim-signature;
        bh=oz3nVaiXvPhENQytolVf3ACAgfI2p8aslAq1BN/w55M=;
        b=fUeNvuOk3JjseXNpa+wFWtdmRjgG/Le5G62cV0ZMbelccGKi1H7GWx
         Exred4q9phvSSGV7ZuE+U5MXpwL1tXmPYZhHO+fj5uPEt6dY2x
         Yqg2/1IxDhcd/3NLH8CB19AolyRgAA8Qn+ThyBgpHs8mCVQ0f5XzxZvP/rKf
         WXxyQwA/1CcOPEcDlaOPAZNngacjvxeecjWWLrHUK1eH
         bETcDxabCPKXagRnP4xDXwTSqzj4Gtjsbc7 +v
         WGfw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mail.com header.s=mail header.b=LRDuMb9q;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of ***@mail.com designates ****.137.**.*** as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=***@mail.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=mail.com
Return-Path: <***@mail.com>
Received: from mail.com (f4mail-235-203. mail.com. [***.137.**.***])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id l10si2328115pgb.331.2021.05.06.03.24.13
        for <xxxxx@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 06 May 2021 03:24:14 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of ***@mail.com designates ***.137.**.*** as permitted sender) client-ip=***.137.**.***;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mail.com header.s=mail header.b=LRDuMb9q;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of ***@mail.com designates ***.137.**.*** as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=***@mail.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=mail.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mail.com;
    s=mail; t=1620296652;
    bh=oz3nVaiXvPhENQytolVf3ACAgfI2p8aslAq1BN/w55M=;
    h=MIME-Version:From:Date:Message-ID:Subject:To:Content-Type;
    b=LRDuMb9qOWYq/u397M6T9zLkk1kInTolxD538xl5crHBsb3PL8eR5GiE0Deg7fTNe
     T8+whLVLTServKQLpxrEE3ob/6c5gr11SFYP8dIyzYU+qhbtxp6OJcAnBuxkJSRgRD
     JFQ/6oaHO49Jhz/2qkQ82USjrCi1fiAZe/mBKUGY=
Received: (qmail 20965 invoked by uid 510); 6 May 2021 10:24:12 -0000
x-m-msg: asd54ad564ad7aa6sd5as6d5; a6da7d6asas6dasd77; 5dad65ad5sd;
X-OUT-VDRT-SpamState: 0\LEGIT
X-OUT-VDRT-SpamScore: 0
X-OUT-VDRT-SpamCause: gggruggvucftvghtrhhoucdtuddrgeduledrvdegtddgvdejucetufdoteggodetrfdotffvucfrrhhofhhilhgvmecufdftgfffkffhhfdpqfgfvfdfnecuuegrihhlohhuthemuceftddtnecunecujfgurhepffggvffkshfuhfgtsegrtderredttdejnecuhfhrohhmpedfrfhrihihrghnkhgrucffvghsrghifdcuoehpihihrgguvghsrghiudduuddusehrvgguihhffhhmrghilhdrtghomheqnecuggftrfgrthhtvghrnheptdefkeehkeduhfeljeelleehgefgffeutdeljedtiedtgeeigfdtjeettedvkedtnecukfhppedurddukeeirdduvdegrdduheeinecuvehluhhsthgvrhfuihiivgeptdenucfrrghrrghmpehmohguvgepshhmthhpohhuth
X-Remote-IP: ***.137.**.***
X-REDF-OSEN: ***@mail.com
Date: 6 May 2021 10:24:12 -0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: "***" <***@gmail.com>
Received: from unknown ***.137.**.*** by mail.com via HTTP; 06 May 2021 10:24:12 -0000
X-Senderscore: D=0&S=0
Message-ID: <1620296512.S.1386.3658.f4mail-***-13*.mail.com.1620296652.20941@webmail.mail.com>
Sender: ***@mail.com
Subject: =?utf-8?B?UmVxdWVzdGVkIGRvY3VtZW50cw==?=
From: "Fisrtname Lastname" <***@mail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="=_f619e79a5c2c1319e417d1bc96f343f8"

--=_f619e79a5c2c1319e417d1bc96f343f8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"



Hey Name,

I hope you are fine and staying safe.
&nbsp;Please find the attached document of some details for the whole process for this program.&nbsp; Once you go through it if you find interest to know then let&#39;s have a discussion.

Regards,
Name LastName
&nbsp;
--=_f619e79a5c2c1319e417d1bc96f343f8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<br /><br />Hey Name,<br /><br />I hope you are fine and staying safe.<br /=
>&nbsp;<div>Please find the attached document of some details for the whole=
 process for this program.&nbsp; Once you go through it if you find interes=
t to know then let&#39;s have a discussion.<br /><br />Regards,<br />Name L=
astName<br />&nbsp;</div><br>
--=_f619e79a5c2c1319e417d1bc96f343f8--
```

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add your code to load eml file and an anonymised eml file. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: For what it's worth, `&nbsp;` in `text/plain` just spells out the six characters `&`, `n`, `b`, `s`, `p`. and `;`. If you want a hard space, use a suitable Unicode character; but in your example, these look purely like noise which you should simply remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the legacy `email.message.Message` API which does not easily let you add attachments to a message you parsed. But it's easy and overall a good idea to switch to the modern Python 3.6+ API which makes this a breeze.

Somewhat obscurely, the way to make the `email.parser` module produce a modern `EmailMessage` object instead of a legacy `Message` one is to pass in a `policy` parameter.

As an aside, you should read the file as `bytes` and use the `BytesParser` to avoid having weird encoding errors if the email message is not pure UTF-8 on disk.  Many real-world messages contain Latin-1 or various Asian character sets; but the proper solution is to not even try to guess - just read it in as a binary blob and let the `email` parser figure it out.

```py
from email.parser import BytesParser
from email.policy import default

headername = 'sender'
headervalue = 'you need to show us your variables <failure@example.net>'

with open(r'C:\Users\Sun\Download\Message.eml', 'rb') as mess:
    message = BytesParser(policy=default).parse(mess)

message.replace_header(headername, headervalue)
message.replace_header('to', 'name@gmail.com')

message.add_attachment(b'\x00\x00\x00', 'attachment', 'pdf', filename='poop.pdf')
```

The `add_attachment` method is also somewhat poorly documented; its arguments are the attachment body data, the main type, and the subtype (though there are additional parameters you can add, like a disposition, to give the recipient a file name for it). See e.g. [Addng attachment to an EmailMessage raises TypeError: set_text_content() got an unexpected keyword argument 'maintype'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56711321/addng-attachment-to-an-emailmessage-raises-typeerror-set-text-content-got-an)

Normally, you'll probably want to read the PDF from a file, too:

```py
from pathlib import Path

pdf_file = Path(r'C:\windows\horrible\atrocious\nasty\file.pdf')
with pdf_file.open('rb') as pdf:
    message.add_attachment(
        pdf.read(), 'attachment', 'pdf', filename=pdf_file.name)
```

Notice how again we require binary input, and how the first argument to `message.add_attachment` is the `bytes` object containing the payload.

The `pathlib` diversion is not strictly necessary here, but shows how to type the file name only once, and pass it to the `filename` keyword parameter of `add_attachment` to use the same file name there, without the directory part.

If you want to write the modified message to the same file, just `close` the file handle (or better, use `with open() ...:` when initially reading it, so you don't have to remember to explicitly `close()`, like I do above) and open for reading, then write out the new content. Again, remember to use binary mode, and write out `bytes`.

```py
with open(filename, 'wb') as destination:
    destination.write(message.as_bytes())
```

Vaguely adapted demo: https://ideone.com/NBMOs1

As a aside, your SMTP server doesn't care what's in the `To:` header; if you `sendmail me@example.org <Message.eml` it will be delivered to me, not to whoever is in the `To:` header. (`sendmail` is not commonly installed on Windows, but the same principle holds.)  Maybe you don't actually want or need to replace the `To:` header if that's your concern.

Comment: message.add_attachment('C:\\Users\\Name\\Downloads\\mypdf.pdf', 'attachment', 'pdf', filename='mypdf.pdf')         This is giving me an error =      LookupError: unknown encoding: pdf

Comment: version is 3.8.5

Comment: Oh wait. I think the linked question about `add_attachment` actually explains how your mistake could produce this error. Anyway, I'll update the answer to spell this out.