# Base64 encoded image is not showing in gmail

Tags: html, gmail, base64, html-email

I have an embedded HTML email in which I'm using a `base64` encoded image. Image doesn't show in gmail when accessing via chrome. But it works fine when accessing same mail via mail client(Mail application on Mac). I have set headers correctly. Any idea?

My code

```
<html>
    <body>Hi
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="273" height="11" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

Headers

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Comment: Gmail does not support base64 embedded images. Yet it allows attached images to be shown.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12786336/4229270

Comment: @lumio Then how does it show correctly in mail client?

Comment: If you using nodemailer, check the solution  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946783/gmail-blocking-small-embedded-inline-images-in-email-template/68532260#68532260)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**base64 encoded images are not well supported in email.** They aren't supported in most web email clients (including Gmail) and are completely blocked in Outlook. Apple Mail is one of the few clients that *does* support them, that's why you're able to see them there but not elsewhere.

---

Another thing to be mindful of with base64 encoded images is email file size. Gmail App (iOS, Android) and Outlook (iOS) truncate email messages whose file size exceeds 102KB. Remotely referenced images (Eg. `<img src="http://www.website.com/image.png">` do not count towards the email's file size, **but base64 encoded images *do*** and can quickly blow out an email's file size past the 102KB limit. Just something else to consider.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is still accurate. I've observed that embedded images don't render in GMail but they do in Outlook.

Comment: Aye, they have _some_ support, but not much. Unfortunately this answer is still mostly accurate. https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-svg/

Comment: That document itself may be inaccurate. Based on recent testing with the native Windows Outlook client, embedded images appear to render correctly.

Comment: Oh interesting! Which version of Windows Outlook do you see embedded SVG displayed in?

Comment: Version 2303 build 16.0.16227.20202. Not embedded SVG though - embedded PNG.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer anymore.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like that direct encoded images (non-bease64 ) are also not supported by gmail :( - I write below snippet to convert image from base64 to direct form and send it in email - but still not see any image :( . To solve this issue you need to add images as attachements with cid and use that cid in img tags `<img src="cid:123456">` - more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110164/860099)

```js
function convert() {
  let base64 = imageBase64.value.split('base64,')[1];
  let hex = [...atob(base64)].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, 0));
  let img = 'data:image/png,%' + hex.join('%');

  pic.src = img;
  msg.innerText = img;
}
```

```html
Put your img base64 data uri here<br>
<input style="width:200px" id='imageBase64' value="data:image/bmp;base64,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">
<button onclick="convert()">Convert</button><br> Result
<br>
<textarea id='msg' rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
<img id='pic'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and used alternative way. Used cid as it was mentioned earlier. I am using aspnet to send html email with embedded base64 so here is an example in C#.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        message.From = new MailAddress(emailTemplate.From);
        message.To.Add(to);
        message.Subject = emailTemplate.SubjectEn;

        string htmlBody = emailTemplate.ContentEn;

        AlternateView htmlView = 
 AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, 
 MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
 string base64Image = "";
 ContentType contentType = new ContentType("image/png");
 LinkedResource linkedImage = new LinkedResource(new 
 System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytes), contentType)
        {
            ContentId = "0123456789"
        };

        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(linkedImage);
        message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this approach found using nodemailer :

attachDataUrls – if true then convert data: images in the HTML content of this message to embedded attachments

link:

https://nodemailer.com/message/#content-options

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, The JavaMailSender already has a helper method.

In your template, have the image tag like the one below.

```
<img src="cid:header-logo">
```

And then, in your email logic, add the attachments as inline.

```
helper.addInline("header-logo", new ClassPathResource("mail/images/header-logo.png"));
```