# Symfony - Image is not displaying in email with swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, email, base64, swiftmailer

I have a Symfony project where I have to send email so I use `Swiftmailer` to do it. Inside my email, I have an image encoded in base64 but in the email the image is not displaying (I have actually the `alt`)... The `base64` disapear but I don't know why and I don't find similar issues.

Here is my code:

```
<img alt="Les Cannelines"
     src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG(...)"
     style="height: 50px;">
```

And here is what I have in the code inspector:

[image: code inspector]

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783599/base64-encoded-image-is-not-showing-in-gmail