# create email with embedded image gmail api

Tags: c#, google-api, base64, gmail-api

I am able to create an email draft using the gmail api. I'm also able to create a draft with an embedded image if the image is a real file.

The next step I want to reach is to create a draft with an embedded image where the image is just a screenshot on my clipboard. By creating the draft my html img tag looks something like

" img width="593" height="363" src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwM......"

but in gmail this part of my draft is empty.

Does someone know any solutions for this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are other images in that email showing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 encoded image is not showing in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783599/base64-encoded-image-is-not-showing-in-gmail)