# How to embed a font inside an html email

Tags: html-email, font-face, mime, embedding

I need to embed a font file into an email message. I know it makes the email bigger, but I need it to be self-contained, meaning no links depending on an internet connection.

I have currently working embedding images using the cid method and it works fine. However, if I use the same mechanism on fonts, it doesn't work.

Namely:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Andale;
        src: url("cid:andale_location") format('woff2');
}
```

when I have somewhere into the MIME:

```
 Content-Type: font/woff2
 Content-Disposition: inline
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 Content-ID: <andale_location>

 d09GMgABAAAAAMEYAA4AAAABikAAAMC7AAE....
```

When I receive an email with that CSS (into the head section of the HTML), both gmail and outlook ignore the font-face part. I get a binary attachment into the email but no fonts whatsoever. Using the font-family "Andale" doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we can't *embed* vector graphics (be it fonts or images) into email; email clients have very poor support for that. More info here: [Base64 encoded image is not showing in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783599/base64-encoded-image-is-not-showing-in-gmail/46789485#46789485)

However we *can* use `@font-face` to render web fonts [in *some* email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/webfonts/), but not all. Depending on what fonts you're designing with, you could specify a font-stack the starts with a custom font and falls back to similar system fonts. Something like:

```
font-family: Andale, Arial, sans-serif;
```

The email won't match pixel perfect in every email client, but maybe it doesn't have to? [More info on email typography, web fonts, and fallbacks](https://litmus.com/blog/typography-tips-for-email-designers).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, I need it to be pixel perfect. I am combining monospace with images in a fixed way and it's impossible without knowing in advance how wide would be a letter, at least without Javascript, and scripts are not allowed either in email messages. That's why I need to make sure I am using a font I already know. I cannot use webfonts because, as I said before, I have to make sure it works without an internet connection. Embedded images work fine, at least as far as I tested them.