# Laravel email shows images fine in Mailtrap but not visible in Gmail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail, mailtrap

I am using a simple Laravel Mailable below and have the header image displayed at the top of the email - this displays fine when going through Mailtrap.io but when the same email is sent to my Gmail account in the live environment it doesn't display - what am I doing wrong?

```
class TwoFactorMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $code;

    public function __construct($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.twofactor');
    }
}
```

Blade file

```
@component('mail::message')
<html>
<head>
    <title>Two Factor</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{base64_encode(file_get_contents(resource_path('img/header.jpg')))}}" alt="">
        <h1 class="header padded-margin">Authentication code</h1><hr class="divider">
        <p>Your Two-Factor Authentication is below. Add the code into your browser to complete your CrowdControlHQ Sign In.</p>
        <div class="code padded-margin">{{ $code }}</div>
        <p>If you didn’t request this code there is nothing to worry about - you can safely ignore it.</p>
</body>
</html>
@endcomponent
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Base64 encoded image is not showing in gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783599/base64-encoded-image-is-not-showing-in-gmail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best to use the standard url based src for your image tag.

Just ensure you include the domain name in the url like this below.

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" alt="img" />
```

Most modern email clients do not accept base64 images.

You can read more about it here

https://blog.mailtrap.io/embedding-images-in-html-email-have-the-rules-changed/

search the page and read about these two subjects

- 1. Inline embedding, or base64 images in emails
- 2. Linked images, or hosted pictures in HTML emails