# Gmail does not show the images in email body?How to show image in Gmail body?

Tags: c#, html

I am sending mail from the email service to one gmail account user and the same mail to outlook account user, but the issue is outlook shows all the content of email body along with images but in gmail the content is shown but image is not visible?

When i inspect the same email from gmail, found out:
-The image tag is empty, attached image for the same
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkBag.png)

But for OUTLOOK user, Image is visible, attached the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEye9.png)

Also checked the settings of gmail and enable the display external images but images still not showing?
How can I do that?

Comment: You are missing your c# with the html encoded email sending code.

Comment: Does gmail disable the base64 images?

Comment: Usually is not a good idea using base64 encoded images. Odly this [related or duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783599/base64-encoded-image-is-not-showing-in-gmail) says in Outlook should not work, but it is a bit old question.

Comment: Why gmail does not show base64 images in it UI?Is there any way to do it?