# Python/Yagmail - How to embed local images into e-mail?

Tags: python, image, email, yagmail

I'm currently using the yagmail module to send e-mails with Python, and I'm having difficulty embedding locally stored images into an e-mail. Is this possible?

Here's a code example:

```
contents = ["<img src='/path/to/local/image'>"]

yag = yagmail.SMTP('myemail@gmail.com', 'password')
yag.send('myotheremail@gmail.com', 'E-mail Title', contents)
```

Using the above code example, if I input an external path (e.g, imgur image or google image), it works perfectly, put I cannot seem to get a local path recognized.

The solution doesn't *have* to be using yagmail, it just seems to be the easiest e-mail module I've used so far.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to attach them to your email: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments

Comment: Can I embed them after they are attached? I forgot to specify, but I need to have them embedded into the e-mail, not just attached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yagmail creator here:

Try this:

```
contents = [yagmail.inline("/path/to/local/image")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the image on a cloud CDN like google drive has this kind of function and send the email as HTML including the picture.