# Create a text file, and email it without saving it locally

Tags: python, email, text

I would like to create a text file in Python, write something to it, and then e-mail it out (put `test.txt` as an email attachment).

However, I cannot save this file locally. Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

As soon as I open the text file to write in, it is saved locally on my computer.

```
f = open("test.txt","w+")
```

I am using `smtplib` and `MIMEMultipart` to send the mail.

Comment: you'd like to send `test.txt` out as one attachment of one email? or put the content of `test.txt` into email body?

Comment: I'd like to send test.txt as the attachment of the email

Comment: I wonder if [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) would be useful here? It's conventionally used for constructing a file-like object without actually creating a file. No idea whether smtplib would accept such a thing though.

Comment: Follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments#3363254 - the `MimeApplication` method doesn't need a file - just its contents and a name to create an attachment from.

Comment: But how would I write text into the file though?

Comment: Why do you want to pollute the file system? Either you already have a file and you want to attach it, or you have a buffer in memory and want to attach that. Saving the buffer in a file is useless and complicates your question needlessly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) is the way to go...

```
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

from io import StringIO

email = MIMEMultipart()
email['Subject'] = 'subject'
email['To'] = 'recipient@example.com'
email['From'] = 'sender@example.com'

# Add the attachment to the message
f = StringIO()
# write some content to 'f'
f.write("content for 'test.txt'")
f.seek(0)

msg = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
msg.set_payload(f.read())
encoders.encode_base64(msg)
msg.add_header('Content-Disposition',
               'attachment',
               filename='test.txt')
email.attach(msg)
```

Comment: I'm able to send a document, but the text file is blank. Also for some reason, it sends two text files as attachments. Not too sure why.  f = StringIO()
    f.write(u'hi')
 

    msg1 = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    msg1.set_payload(f.read())
    #encoders.encode_base64(msg)
    msg1.add_header('Content-Disposition',
               'attachment',
               filename='test.txt')
    msg.attach(msg1)

Comment: Got it - it should be msg.set_payload(f.getvalue())

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while figuring out how to do this with the newer EmailMessage, which was introduced in Python 3.6 (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html). It's slightly less code:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
from io import StringIO
from smtplib import SMTP

message = EmailMessage()
message['Subject'] = 'Subject'
message['From'] = 'from@example.com'
message['To'] = 'to@example.com'

f = StringIO()
f.name = 'attachment.txt'
f.write('contents of file')
f.seek(0)
message.add_attachment(f.read(), filename=f.name)
with SMTP('yourmailserver.com', 25) as server:
    server.send_message(message)
```