# How to send an email attachement with python and gmail? (python Smtplib - Permission Denied [Errno 13] )

Tags: python, gmail, email-attachments, smtplib

I want to know how i can attach a pdf to my mail. Sending a mail is not a problem - just the attachement is. So you probably have seen that error before and im already sorry for asking again BUT i literally cant find any solution for this - that works for me. I tried everything i could find for example:

- Python shortcut with the filename at the end
- Give the script and the folder admin Privileges
- Starting my CMD as admin as well

I think that are the most common solutions to the problem but they are not working for me. The following is the code i use. At the open() the problem appears but i think the people that can help me here know how the rest looks anyway. Its pretty basic, i used nothing fancy. Btw downloading an attachement was easy aswell, just sending it is ...

```
path = "C:/****/.../****"

attachment = open(path, "rb")
```

Hope you all have a great day!

Comment: Here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments

Comment: Here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments

Comment: Just use this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments
You could google a bit before asking.
>

Comment: @Atom I already tried that - but nope. Read first please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to read the file in your script ?

usually I use `attachment =  open(r"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\the_file")` to attach a file