# How to send pytest coverage report via email?

Tags: python, django, pytest, code-coverage, coverage.py

I am using pytest framework and pytest-cov plugin to get the coverage report generated, which generates a coverage report file inside htmlcov directory after the test cases are executed, is there a way where I can also send this report file as an attachment while the test cases are executed?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "while the test cases are executed"? You could generically use python's smtplib (https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) to send an email of the html report after the execution is done.

Comment: @JackThomson I meant after the test cases are executed when the coverage Html report is generated, can I make a provision to send the generated report via mail, that when the test case are executed the coverage report is added as an attachment and sent via mail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a teardown script in your conftest.py file. This is where you can put your pytest fixtures as well as generic pytest options. See the API reference [here.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionfinish)

`pytest_session_finish` is the function you're looking for. Your `conftest.py` could look something like this. This heavily references [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments) for the smtplib section with an attachment:

```py
import smtplib
from os.path import basename
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate


def send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=None,
              server="127.0.0.1"):
    assert isinstance(send_to, list)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    for f in files or []:
        with open(f, "rb") as fil:
            part = MIMEApplication(
                fil.read(),
                Name=basename(f)
            )
        # After the file is closed
        part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
        msg.attach(part)


    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()

def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    send_mail('myemail', 'theiremail', 'Your Coverage Report', 'My Text',
        files="coveragereport.html", server="myserver")
```