# How to auto email test failures with pytest or other python packages?

Tags: python, email, pytest, smtplib

I have a page and test class, the test class looks something like below

```
import unittest
import pytest
import logging

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class BigRandomTest(unittest.TestCase):
    log = cl.testogger(logging.DEBUG)

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classSetup(self):
        self.synMax = CarMaxSyndicated()

    # Standard set of tests
    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_column_uniqueness_dealership(self):
        pass
        self.log.debug('List of all column duplicate counts: \n' + str(result[1]))
        assert result[0].empty, 'Test failed. Columns with a suspect amount of duplicates: \n {}'.format(result[0])
    
    @pytest.mark.run(order=2)
    def test_column_uniqueness_consistency_dealership(self):
        pass
        self.log.debug('List of all column duplicates differences: \n' + str(result[1]))
        assert result[0].empty, 'Test failed. Columns with significantly different duplicate counts between collections: \n {}'.format(result[0])
```

when I run the pytest -s -v path_to_test --html=result.html --self-contained-html it generates the report but what I want to do is email the report whenever there is a test failure only, I can setup some stmp or if there is a package that I can use it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what the full code for conftest.py would look like for this situation:

conftest.py

```py
import pytest
import smtplib
import ssl
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

failed: bool = False


def send_email():
    """
    function to send an email with attachment after all test are run and a failure was detected
    """
    subject: str = "subject"
    body: str = "body"
    sender_email: str = "email"
    receiver_email: str = "email"
    password: str = "password"  # Recommended for mass emails# This should obviously be an input or some other stronger protection object other than a string
    smtp: str = "smtp"
    filename: str = "result.html"
    port: int = 587

    # Attachments need to be multipart
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message["From"] = sender_email
    message["To"] = receiver_email
    message["Subject"] = subject
    message["Bcc"] = receiver_email
    # Add body to email
    message.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))

    # Open html file in binary mode
    # This will only work if HTML file is located within the same dir as the script
    # If it is not, then you will need to modify this to the right path
    with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
        # Add file as application/octet-stream
        # Email client can usually download this automatically as attachment
        part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload(attachment.read())

    # Encode file in ASCII characters to send by email
    encoders.encode_base64(part)

    # Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
    part.add_header(
        "Content-Disposition",
        f"attachment; filename= {filename}",
    )

    # Add attachment to message and convert message to string
    message.attach(part)
    text = message.as_string()

    # Log in to server using secure context and send email
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp, port) as server:
        server.starttls(context=context)
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, text)


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    global failed
    report = yield
    result = report.get_result()

    if result.when == 'call' and result.outcome == "failed":
        failed = True
        print("FAILED")


def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    if failed is True:
        send_email()
```

There are two key functions within this file.

- pytest_runtest_makereport
- pytest_session

pytest_runtest_makereport will run after every test and simply check if the test failed or not. If any test fails, then the `failed` flag will be set to True.

Then at the end of the whole script, pytest_session will run and check if the flag was changed to True. If it was, then an email will be sent with the result.html file attached.

I would like to highlight that part of this question was previously answered before, see the link below:
[How to send pytest coverage report via email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60647285/how-to-send-pytest-coverage-report-via-email)

Given the linked question/answer did not contain any information on how to only run if a test failed. I decided it was worth answering here.