# TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] in Windows Server while using smtplib

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib

I am trying to send mail using smtplib module. I was able to successfully send email using my `Windows-7 PC`, but while I was trying the same code in `Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 64-bit(6.1, Build 7601)`  I am getting `TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]`.

Code attached below.

```
def send_email(from_addr, to_addr_list,
              subject, html_body,plain_text_body,
              login,
              password,
              smtpserver='smtp.gmail.com:587',
              cc_addr_list=None,
              attachment=None,
              from_name=None):

    message=MIMEMultipart()

    plain=MIMEText(plain_text_body,'plain')
    #html=MIMEText(html_body,'html') 

    message.add_header('from',from_name)
    message.add_header('to',','.join(to_addr_list))
    message.add_header('subject',subject)

    if attachment!=None:
        attach_file=MIMEApplication(open(attachment,"rb").read())
        attach_file.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="%s"' % attachment)
        message.attach(attach_file)


    message.attach(plain)
    #message.attach(html)

    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver) #TimeoutError raised on this line 
    server.starttls()
    server.login(login,password)
    server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr_list, message.as_string())
    server.quit()
    print("MailSent")
```

I am getting error in below line

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
```

Error message attached below

```
"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 728, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I have tried all the below options, I am getting the same `TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]`;

1. I have enabled "Allow Less Secure Apps" option in Gmail account.
2. `Server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)`
3. `Server = smtplib.SMTP ("smtp.gmail.com", 587)`
4. `Server = smtplib.SMTP ("smtp.gmail.com", 587, timeout=120)`
5. `Server = smtplib.SMTP ("smtp.gmail.com:587”)`
6. I have allowed port 587 and 465 in firewall Inbound and Outbound rules.
7. I have also tried `yagmail` module (I am getting same error)

Am I missing something? or any alternative solution much appreciated.

Comment: did you try `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` or similar connectivity tools, which would provide an overview of whether the gmail's smtp server is able to connect from that Windows Server?

Comment: In Windows Server i am able to login to gmail from Chrome.

Comment: Hey Bhuvan, Chrome uses port 80/443 (https/http) to connect to gmail. Can you confirm with the above command? I mean, can you run that in your terminal? maybe you have to install telnet client once.

Comment: What do you have in to_addr_list?

Comment: For testing From and To both are same.

Comment: I am getting the same error. May I know how you have solved it.

Comment: It was a computer permission problem, Then I tried with local mail server worked for me, below link might help. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments/3363254#336325`